# Yii2 - Send data to a webservice

Tags: php, xml, web-services, yii2, yii2-web-service

I need sending data to a webservice SOAP 3 fields  using POST, how to do this in Yii2?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://link" xmlns:xsd="http://link" xmlns:soap="http://link">
  <soap:Body>
    <Insert xmlns="http://web_service">
      <id>my_id</id>
      <value>my_value</value>
      <date>my_date</date>
    </Insert>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

sorry my bad english :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use php's [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) class.

As I see, you need to call the "Insert" method, with 3 parameters, here is how you can do it:

```php
// Your WS URL
$endpoint = "some.url.com/service.asmx?WSDL";

// The SOAP client
$client = new \SoapClient($endpoint);

// The parameters you want to pass
$data = ['id' => 'my_id', 'value' => 'my_value', 'date' => 'my_date'];

// Call the "Insert" function of the WS with the params
$result = $client->Insert($data);
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems that many people did not realize my question (it has already been edited) but you understand thanks, I already managed to send the data, now how do I see an response in XML or similar? to make sure the data was sent correctly.